# how to check for closed addition and closed multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

When checking if a set is in the subspace, I'm checking for the $0$ vector, closed addition and closed multiplication. I've verified all set have the zero vector since $x,y,z$ and $s,t$ are all in $R$ and can be set to $0$. But how do i check closed addition/multiplication?

Comment: addition: you take two arbitrary elements from the set, add them and check whether the result is in the set. (scalar) mulitplication: you take a scalar and an element $x$ of the set, multiply $x$ by the scalar and check whether the result is in the set.

Answer (score 1):

1. $U_1$ is not a subspace: See that $x=(1,2,3)\in U_1$ but $\ -1.x \notin U_1$
2. $U_2$ is not a subspace: $(1,1,1) ,(0,1,2)\in U_2$ but their sum doesn't belongs to $U_2$.
3. $U_3$ is the Linear span of $\{(1,0,0),(0,0,1)\} $, so a subspace.
4. $U_4$ is not a subspace. you can check it is not closed under addition.
5. $\{(0,0,0)\}$ is a subspace. since it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.
6. $U_6= \text{Null space of} ~A$, where 
   $A=\begin{bmatrix}
       1       & 1 & -1\\
       2       & 1 & 1 \\
   \end{bmatrix}$.
   Hence $U_6$ is also a subspace.